# active_admin_form_for doesn't recognise model's attributes in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, arb

I have a form like this:

revoke.html.arb

```
active_admin_form_for resource, url: revoke_active_admin_payment_subscription_path(resource) do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :suspended_at, as: :datepicker, datepicker_options: { max_date: Date.today.iso8601 }
  end
  f.actions
end
```

But the view is crashing with this error:

```
undefined method `suspended_at' for #<Forms::Payment::SubscriptionForm:0x00007f36462aaae8>
Did you mean?  suspended_at_from_model
```

if I change to use `suspended_at_from_model` the page loads, but the name, id, and label for the input are all `suspended_at_from_model` instead of simply `suspended_at`

Why can't the form accept `suspended_at` for the input?

Comment: did you try this ? `active_admin_form_for [:payment_subscription, resource] ... do |f|`

Comment: Yea I tried `active_admin_form_for [:payment_subscription, resource]`, `active_admin_form_for [:admin, :payment_subscription, resource]`, `active_admin_form_for [:active_admin, :payment_subscription, resource]`, none of them work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `resource` is the form, not the model. In this case, you need something like:

```
active_admin_form_for resource.model, url: revoke_active_admin_payment_subscription_path(resource) do |f|
```